# setting new shortcut for tag search on emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, tags, keyboard-shortcuts, org-mode

This is probably simple, but I've been trying it for a couple days now without success. I have a tag called :urgent:, which I can access through:

```
C-c / m urgent
```

Question is, how can I create a shortcut to get it done with, say, f9?

Comment: How about something like?  `(defun hello-world () "My doc-string." (interactive) (org-tags-view nil "urgent"))` and `(global-set-key [f9] 'hello-world)` **or** `(define-key global-map [f9] 'hello-world)`

Comment: @lawlist this is exactly what i needed, thanks a ton. note to self: need to learn elisp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(defun hello-world ()
"My doc-string."
(interactive)
  (org-tags-view nil "urgent"))

(global-set-key [f9] 'hello-world)
;; or, use the following form instead of the one immediately above:
;; (define-key global-map [f9] 'hello-world)
```